# Plymouth on Debian 8 starts late and stops early

Tags: debian, boot

I'm running Debian 8.1 on a Dell Inspiron 15-3521. I've followed [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth) to get plymouth installed on my machine, but it only partially works. As you can see in [this video I've taken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxjILoMlukY), plymouth doesn't seem to start until after some text output is already displayed on the screen, and it stops before the machine fully boots up as well. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Should this be migrated to the SuperUser site?

Answer (score 2):

Plymouth can be started early on the boot process by reducing the delay in Plymouth configuration file

In /etc/plymouth/plymouthd.conf ,add below line

```
ShowDelay=0
```

After this you need to update initramfs of the system with following command

```
update-initramfs -u
```

The early quitting is due to plymouth-quit service being called early in the boot process.
To quit plymouth late you need to learn the boot process.You need to know how systemd works to call plymouth quit service late.